# How to assign a record for approval to a managers manager

Tags: approval-process, user

I have a requirement where I need to send a record for approval to the managers manager level. Eg: If A have manager as B and B have manager C. I have a condition that if the the qty is less than 10 the send it to B (Manager of A). IF qty is greater than 10 the send the to B as well as to C (Manager of Manager A). For this I have created a formula field on User to get the user id of the managers manager. I have 2 steps - In first I assigned the record approve to Manager, but in 2 step i need to select the formula field where it refer to managers manager. Is this possible to do from Approval process. Or we need to implement anything else. Please guide me the best way to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

the solution is to approve along the manager's hierarchy. In a first approval step, the record is to be approved by the manager. Instead of letting the process end, the record is fed into a second approval step, where it is again forwarded to the manager (= the manager's manager). see http://www.cloudprofessionals.biz/salesforce-advanced-approvals-auto-approvals-and-approval-by-managers-manager/ for details.

Formula fields cant work, they deliver text (e.g. names only). To approve via named users you have to include a custom user field to your object.